# For loop to print two dimensinal array

Tags: java

Hi Am trying to print 2 dimensional array using for loop. Many places I see nested for loop like

```
for (..)
  for (..).
```

But how to print using for loop in declaration and expression . for single dimensional following works

```
for ( String print_fruit_names : fruit_names )
{
  sysout (names);
};
```

Am a newbie in java. please let me know if am missing any info to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this [with a for each using a Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work):

```
String[][] matrix = {{"one", "two", "three"}, {"four", "five", "six"}};

for (String[] sArray: matrix){
  for (String s: sArray){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Or, you could do it like this which just accesses each index directly:

```
String[][] matrix = {{"one", "two", "three"}, {"four", "five", "six"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
```